# how to find missing number in string through list comprehension in python

Tags: python

This question is asked in interview to convert string in integer.

```
str='1,3,5,8,...,12,15,17,...,21,22'
```

the objective is find missing number in string 
The output should be string like this

```
'1,2,3,8,9,10,11,12,15,17,18,19,20,21,11'
```

i done this with lengthy code,

```
s='1,3,5,8,...,12,15,17,...,21,22'
s_list = s.split(',')
new_list=[]
t=0
for ch in s_list:
    if ch.isdigit():
        t=int(ch)
        new_list.append(ch)
    else:
        for i in range(1,len(ch)+1):
            t+=1
            new_list.append(str(t))
print ",".join(new_list)
```

but
Need optimized solution, use list comprehension.

Comment: So what is your solution, can you share that code? And the output doesn't make much sense; where did `5` go, where did the `2` come from, what's the `11` at the end? What does the extra quote in the expected output do?

Comment: If you do `str = ',' + str` and define `result = []` you could do `[result.extend([int(element[1])] if element[1].isnumeric() else range(int(element[0])+1, int(element[2]))) for element in list(zip_longest(str.split(','), str.split(',')[1:], str.split(',')[2:]))[:-1]]`. Of course that's unreadable and noone with a sane mind would do it this way.

Answer (score 3):

```
str = '1,2,3'
int_list = [int(x) for x in str.split(',')]
```

This will give you a list with integers by first splitting `str` and converting each individual item/slice into a `int` via `int(x)`.
Quite self explanatory I guess, but if you're wondering over anything just ask in the comment section and I'll do my best to explain. Have a good one!

The method used is called [List Comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

### Edit (Finding missing values in a list of integers):

Since this answer might not apply and the question is on hold I'll go even deeper on this one in case someone finds this question.

If you're looking for find which numbers are missing in your newly created `int` based `list`, you could do the following:

```
str = '1,2,5'
int_list = [int(x) for x in str.split(',')]

missing_values = []
for i in range(0, max(int_list)):
    if not i in int_list:
        missing_values.append(i)

print('Missing values are:', missing_values)
```

Might be or not be what you're looking for, but I have a hunch this is what you were actually asking.

### Edit 2 (Merging two lists and converting a list of integers to a string):

Spinning further down the rabbit hole on this one through the comment section below.
Imagine that you **want to insert the missing values to your original string**, then you can do the following:

```
int_list = int_list + missing_values
int_list.sort()
```

And finally, you'd might want to convert it back to a string?
Easy does it..

```
str = ','.join(int_list)
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP asked for, actually. I'm not sure at all what it is the OP is asking for, to be frank.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Just noticed the title changed and the question become totally different. Should I remove my answer perhaps?

Comment: In my opinion the OP wants the `...` replaced by the numbers that would fit in this gap.

Comment: @Matthias It's funny that you can evolve the OP's question into a never ending answer, but i'll keep adding as long as the comments grow here because I don't want to get down voted to oblivion.

Comment: @Torxed: unless it was edited in the first 5 minutes, the question did not change. Only the title was updated.